# Converting from C# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

http://wiki.team-mediaportal.com/MediaPortal1_Development/PluginDevelopersGuide#Appendix_A:_complete_source_code_of_the_plugin

Trying to translate the first "test"-code to VB.NET and it doesn't work. It compiles alright, but won't work as planned.

I would guess it has something to do with the "Implements"-statement or something else related to how the class treats the interface. As a completely fresh .NET programmer I really would need your help figuring out why it doesn't work. Here's the converted and edited code below:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports MediaPortal.GUI.Library
Imports MediaPortal.Dialogs

Namespace OurPlugin
    Public Class Class1
#Region "ISetupForm Members"
        Inherits GUIWindow
        Implements ISetupForm

        Public Sub New()

        End Sub

        ' Returns the name of the plugin which is shown in the plugin menu
        Public Function PluginName() As String Implements MediaPortal.GUI.Library.ISetupForm.PluginName
            Return "MyFirstPlugin"
        End Function

        ' Returns the description of the plugin is shown in the plugin menu
        Public Function Description() As String Implements MediaPortal.GUI.Library.ISetupForm.Description
            Return "My First Plugin"
        End Function

        ' Returns the author of the plugin which is shown in the plugin menu
        Public Function Author() As String Implements MediaPortal.GUI.Library.ISetupForm.Author
            Return "YourNameHere"
        End Function

        ' show the setup dialog
        Public Sub ShowPlugin() Implements MediaPortal.GUI.Library.ISetupForm.ShowPlugin
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing to configure, this is just an example")
        End Sub

        ' Indicates whether plugin can be enabled/disabled
        Public Function CanEnable() As Boolean Implements MediaPortal.GUI.Library.ISetupForm.CanEnable
            Return True
        End Function

        ' Get Windows-ID
        Public Function GetWindowId() As Integer Implements MediaPortal.GUI.Library.ISetupForm.GetWindowId
            ' WindowID of windowplugin belonging to this setup
            ' enter your own unique code
            Return 5678
        End Function

        ' Indicates if plugin is enabled by default;
        Public Function DefaultEnabled() As Boolean Implements MediaPortal.GUI.Library.ISetupForm.DefaultEnabled
            Return True
        End Function

        ' indicates if a plugin has it's own setup screen
        Public Function HasSetup() As Boolean Implements MediaPortal.GUI.Library.ISetupForm.HasSetup
            Return True
        End Function

        ''' <summary>
        ''' If the plugin should have it's own button on the main menu of MediaPortal then it
        ''' should return true to this method, otherwise if it should not be on home
        ''' it should return false
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="strButtonText">text the button should have</param>
        ''' <param name="strButtonImage">image for the button, or empty for default</param>
        ''' <param name="strButtonImageFocus">image for the button, or empty for default</param>
        ''' <param name="strPictureImage">subpicture for the button or empty for none</param>
        ''' <returns>true : plugin needs it's own button on home
        ''' false : plugin does not need it's own button on home</returns>

        Public Function GetHome(ByRef strButtonText As String, ByRef strButtonImage As String, ByRef strButtonImageFocus As String, ByRef strPictureImage As String) As Boolean Implements MediaPortal.GUI.Library.ISetupForm.GetHome
            strButtonText = [String].Empty
            strButtonImage = [String].Empty
            strButtonImageFocus = [String].Empty
            strPictureImage = [String].Empty
            Return False
        End Function

        ' With GetID it will be an window-plugin / otherwise a process-plugin
        ' Enter the id number here again
        Public Overloads Overrides Property GetID() As Integer
            Get
                Return 5678
            End Get

            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            End Set
        End Property

#End Region

    End Class
End Namespace
```

[EDIT]

Just to clarify. From the URL I pasted above I noticed I had an incorrect anchor. I'm not testing the complete sourcecode, but only the first "testcode" from this URL: http://wiki.team-mediaportal.com/MediaPortal1_Development/PluginDevelopersGuide#Implementing_GUIWindow_and_ISetupForm

The problem I am having is that it won't show up as a plugin in MediaPortal. The sample in C# works perfectly. Feels like I need to work this thing through before I move on to the GUI-part. I have no idea how to bugtest this since it needs to be loaded as a plugin in MediaPortal to see if it is working.

Comment: What exactly does it do or not do that you're expecting? And what's the class look like in C#?

Answer (score 0):

Notes on a quick comparison:

1. You aren't defining buttonOne or buttonTwo
2. The entire Init method is missing from your code
3. I don't know if GetID being 5678 is of significance or not, but it's worth researching more on your end